# Symfony Customize Form Validator for a set number of options

Tags: forms, symfony-1.4, validation

I have a form with the following widget and validator:

```
  $this->widgetSchema['num01'] = new sfWidgetFormChoice(array(
  'choices' => Doctrine_Core::getTable('ticket')->getTicketnum(),
  'expanded' => true, 'multiple' => true,
   ));

  $this->validatorSchema['num01'] = new sfValidatorChoice(array(
   'choices' =>
   array_keys(Doctrine_Core::getTable('ticket')->getTicketnum()), 'required' => true, 'multiple' => true,
   ));
```

The problem that I'm having is that it displays 20 checkboxes and I would like to make them select only 5 of them.   No more and no less.   It has to be exactly 5 boxes checked.   How can I customize my code to make this validate that way?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this just to see if it would work and it did.   :)

```
$this->validatorSchema['num01'] = new sfValidatorChoice(array(
   'choices' =>
   array_keys(Doctrine_Core::getTable('ticket')->getTicketnum()), 'required' => true,
   'multiple' => true, 'max' => 5, 'min' => 5,
   ));
```